# Redis nodejs get filter

Tags: php, node.js, redis

I'v faced the problem that nodeJS redis library dont have any way to get data by id that PHP library can.

This is nodeJS code:

```
var client = redis.createClient();
client.hgetall('auth', function (err, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

$this is php code that returns value by $auth_inner_key id

```
$redis()->hGet('auth', $auth_inner_key);
```

The questions is - do nodejs redis have any way to get the same value or i need to look throught all of the auth results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get a particular value for a key  from a hash set - nodejs

```
var client = redis.createClient();
  client.hget('auth',"auth_inner_key", function (err, obj) {
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about client.get ?

```
var client = redis.createClient();
client.get('auth', function (err, value) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(value);
});
```